# Someone Knows of a Viewer GUI opening Patch file for Reading Only?

Tags: gui, patch

Back in Precise 12.04 I was using a `GUI Viewer for *.patch` files which `only opened them for reading`, which is fine, as they are generated by cmd. line. This GUI did set itself as default I think shortly after I installed Bazaar related packages (bzr-explorer, etc ...). I didn't paid much attention to know exactly what was this app. On occasion I used `gEdit` whenever I needed to modify a patch file.

However upgrading to Trusty 14.04 and transferring all my set of packages, right now I have `Scribes Text Editor` which sets itself as `default viewer`. Unfortunately this viewer allows (by default) writing in a .patch file ... has a deep black background and no side panel giving access to the different patched files.

The Viewer I was using in Precise 12.04 had a white background, color text, and on the left pane the list of modified files which was handy to navigate a whole patched directory structure. And it never allowed opening for writing.

Does anyone knows exactly what was this *.patch file viewer ? Thanks. Sometimes there is some unexpected drawbacks when upgrading ...

Could it be the `loggerhead` package `Web viewer for Bazaar` ?

This application does crash at startup :

```
$ /usr/bin/loggerhead.wsgi
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/loggerhead.wsgi", line 27, in <module>
from paste.deploy.config import PrefixMiddleware
ImportError: No module named deploy.config
$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that this capability has nothing to do with `loggerhead`.

From the log file of the re-install all packages cmd. line :

```
$ sudo dpkg --set-selections < Precise.12.04.Installed.Packages.Marius-PC.New.log
```

I found at line 61 `dpkg: warning: package not in database at line 191: bzr-gtk` along with 4 other `bzr-*` packages. Meaning that these 5 packages are unavailable for Trusty 14.04.

A quick search gave me more information @ http://wiki.bazaar.canonical.com/bzr-gtk where the latest sources are said to be only compatible with bzr >= 2.1 and <= 2.5. In Trusty 14.04 the used bzr version is 2.6.0. The latest package was available in the [Bazaar Daily Builds](https://launchpad.net/~bzr/+archive/ubuntu/daily) ppa build for Precise 12.04.

This picture is the way it looked in an ancient release of Ubuntu...

[image: Bazaar view (in full screen) of a diff / patch file]

So unless there is some source adjustment this package is now dead.